# How to import through another file in python

Tags: python, import

I want to cut down on the lines of code that do the import.

In foo.py, there are several imports.

```
from a import aa
from b import bb
from c import cc
```

I want to change it like this in foo.py

```
from bar import wonderful_import  #just one line
```

and bar.py is probably like this

```
from a import aa
from b import bb
from c import cc

# or

def wonderful_import():
   from a import aa
   from b import bb
   from c import cc
```

But this doesn't work as I expected. How can I shorten the import line?

Comment: The question is not so clear. Please try to rephrase the question.  Specially you second import - `from bar import wonderful/-import` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import everything from a module called `bar`,
you do this in another module say foo

```
from bar import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you can refer to. Also, to import everything from a python file, you can use a `*`. In your case, it is `from bar import *`

bbdf.py

```
print("Hello World 2")
```

focd.py

```
print("Hello World")
```

dc.py

```
def change():
    import focd
    import bbdf
```

main.py

```
import dc
dc.change()
```

So when I run the file:
Output:

```
Hello World  
Hello World 2
```